# goaccess nginx parsing not working

Tags: logging, nginx, analyzer, web-statistics

'm trying to get goaccess working. Already take some time on docs and examples but without success.

Basically i have log lines like:

*date_format %d/%b/%Y

log_format %^, %h - - [%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^*

*cat ~/.goaccessrc*

212.184.128.232, 173.245.51.215 - - [10/Oct/2013:05:21:49 -0400]  "POST /jstats HTTP/1.1" 200 570 "http://www.ebookl.com
/url?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffilepost.com%2Ffiles%2Fecb82m4d%2FPDF2ID.Professional.v4.0.rar%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel 
Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1" "-"

Then i got:

[F1]Help [O]pen detail view  0 - Thu Oct 10 05:56:52 2013                                         [Q]uit Analyzer 0.5
GoAccess - version 0.5 - Jun 29 2012 13:13:26

An error has occurred
Error occured at: goaccess.c - render_screens - 239
Message: Nothing valid to process.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (assuming the second IP is the remote host)

```
date_format %d/%b/%Y
log_format %^, %h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```